# Separating GUI from main code

Tags: python-2.7, tdd, pyside

I'm trying to improve my coding method, and one thing I would like to try is to take a TDD approach. I read quite few articles and tutorials about it, but as often, without practical examples or testing, this won't stay long in my brain and I will miss lots of fine details.

That's why I'm trying to develop a simple application to make files and directory research in folders. However, here is my problem: I would like to use a GUI, and not a console like application.

I have already been using PySide for other application and I know its basics, but I always avoided bothering with separating UI and main app features (I know, very bad !)

For a TDD approach, I think this is the right time to learn how to do it. Indeed, I could read that to do TDD with GUI, the graphical part must, logically, just be a "bonus layer", added on the top of the logic, and that the tests should first test internal logic, and then that the developer can test UI more or less manually...

So here is the question: how to separate my UI class (derivating from a class generated using pyside-uic) from the rest of my program and how can I make them communicate (for simple application data IO only then)? How can I emit and use signals outside of this class?

Thanks in advance for your help and advice, hoping I'm beeing understandable with my English writting!

Manu

---

EDIT: My first thoughts and readings are going through subclassing QThread and communicate with signal/slot mechanism... Is this absolutely necessary and the only way to do it?

Comment: Implement application logic and features in separate files as classes, then import them to your GUI file.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I'm still quite uncertain in oo design, so thanks a lot for the advice. So I develop/test my logic separately and then, I instanciate and use appropriate classes and methods in my GUI class slots when matching action is required by user input ?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Implement your application logic using classes (if appropriate; it doesn't always make sense to use classes for every application. If it doesn't make sense for your use case, you can just implement functions in separate files and import those files to use the functions), then import the external files into your GUI script. For example, you can have a button event handler simply call a method from one of those external classes/libraries.

Comment: I'll add an answer with a more concrete example.

Comment: also see http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Indeed, most of my "deep" programming questions are actually more focused on this StackExchange site, so thanks a lot for the enlightenment, I'll check also this one afterwards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your main application logic as classes, or, if that doesn't make sense for your use case, just libraries of functions, in separate files. Then, have another file for your GUI script which imports your other files/classes.

**my_example_functions_library.py**

```
import sys
def print_message():
    print "You pressed the `Enter` key!"
```

**my_gui.py**

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from my_example_functions_library import *

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event handler')
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print_message()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very precise ! I'll try that very soon (I only work on this short project as side work form my main projects) !